# Highcharts Stacked Range z-Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Looking at this [script](https://jsfiddle.net/g9zr2u59/): (JsFiddle isn't displaying the graphs for me, for some reason, but it works as html)

I have two overlapping ranges but I'm unable to have one pair bring blue to the front, the other black. Click on 'Task 2' to see that the above blue range is hidden.

I've tried using the z-index option but I can only set it by series not by pair.

Full code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container1" style="min-width: 400px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
$(function () {

    window.chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: true
        },

        title: {
            text: "Top Chart"
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Customer A', 'Customer B']
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Math.abs(this.value);
                }
            }
        },
         tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
                    'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                grouping: false
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Task 1',
            stack: 'Tasks',
            data: [{
                x: 0,
                low: -5,
                high: 5
            }, {
                x: 1,
                low: -15,
                high: 15
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Task 2',
            stack: 'Tasks',
            data: [{
                x: 0,
                low: -10,
                high: 10
            }, {
                x: 1,
                low: -3,
                high: 3
            }]
        }]

    });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way for achieving this is to provide [pointPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbar%3E.pointPadding)  to specific series in charts. This option allows both bars to be visible even it is overlapping each other.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/myuab95oTWhxuAuzMI9R?p=preview) demo

```
   series: [{
        name: 'Task 1',
        stack: 'Tasks',
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            low: -5,
            high: 5
        }, {
            x: 1,
            low: -15,
            high: 15
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Task 2',
        stack: 'Tasks',
        pointPadding: 0.3, /*pointPadding to specific series*/
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            low: -10,
            high: 10
        }, {
            x: 1,
            low: -3,
            high: 3
        }]
    }]
```

Comment: That will work just fine :) And yeah I was worried about the overlapping as well.